# how to make live search on a table with all paging in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sqlite

when i gonna for search about row the result search and show in the current page
how to make live search on a table with all paging ?
don't tell me show us what you have done
the result is table with paging each page content table with 5 rows

> filterTable.js

```
(function(document) {
'use strict';

var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
            });
        });
    }

    function _filter(row) {
        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';
    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('form-control');
            Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
            });
        }
    };
})(Array.prototype);

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        LightTableFilter.init();
    }
});})(document);
```

> Show_Product.php

```
      <input type="search" class="form-control" data-table="table-striped table-bordered table-hover"  id="autocomplete" name="search">

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">

                    </table>
    <?php
                $servername = "localhost";
                $username = "root";
                $password = "";
                $dbname = "msk";

                $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                }
                $query = "select p.productname,p.quantity,p.onesale,p.wholesale,s.fullname from productdetails p , supplier s where s.supplierid = p.supplierID";
                $resultt = $conn->query($query);

                $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($resultt);

                $per_page=5;

                        if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
                            $page = $_GET["page"];
                        }

                        else {
                            $page=1;
                        }

                        $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;

                $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

                echo "<div class=\"widget-foot\">";
                echo "<ul class=\"pagination pagination-sm pull-right\" dir=\"rtl\">";
                if($page<$total_pages) {
                    echo "<li><a href='Show_Product.php?page=" . ($page + 1) . "'>Next</a></li>";
                }
                for ($i=$total_pages; $i>=1; $i--) {
                    echo "<li><a href='Show_Product.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a></li>";
                };
                if($page>1){
                echo "<li><a href='Show_Product.php?page=".($page-1)."'>Previous</a></li>";
                }
                echo"</ul>";
                echo"<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>";
                $conn ->close();
                ?>
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? You've got filtering code up there already.

Comment: it search only in one page that current page ..

Comment: how do you expect the JS code to be able to search for what doesn't exist in the page already? it's scanning the live dom. if a page of results hasn't been fetched/displayed from the server yet, then there's nothing for the JS to search.

Comment: i want from it to search on all paging not only in current page

Comment: js code can filter the table and show only the required row but it can filter only in current page ..

Comment: i want to filter all paging that showing data

Comment: then either force js to fetch all of the result pages, or do the searching on the server.

Comment: ok .. how to force js to fetch all of the result pages ?